# Assigning function using Prototype Event.Observe doesn't work in IE(7)

Tags: internet-explorer, events, function, prototypejs, onload

hopefully you can help.  I've built a page with a form on it with a group of radio buttons and I want to assign a function to the onClick of each that will change the style and highlight which radio is selected.  This has been working in an old version of the code that used directly assigned onClick events, but while updating it I need to change these to functions assigned at runtime using the Event system.  I'm using Prototype 1.6.0.1 and the following code works fine in FF, but not IE:

HTML:

```
<form name="the_form" onsubmit="investmentPreApply(); return false;" id="the_form">
   <fieldset class="investment-apply-box1">
      <label for="cautious" id="cautiousLabel" class="isa-option">
         <input type="radio" id="cautious" name="radios" value="cautious" />Cautious Portfolio
      </label>
      <label for="balanced" id="balancedLabel" class="isa-option">
         <input type="radio" id="balanced" name="radios" value="balanced" />Balanced Portfolio
      </label>
      <label for="adventurous" id="adventurousLabel" class="isa-option">
         <input type="radio" id="adventurous" name="radios" value="adventurous" />Adventurous Portfolio
      </label>
      <label for="mixed" id="mixedLabel" class="isa-option">
         <input type="radio" id="mixed" name="radios" value="mixed" />Invest in a bit of each
      </label>
      <div class="isa-body-text-hidden" id="error-text">Please choose your ISA above</div>
   </fieldset>
   <div class="investment-apply-box2">

      <!--Lots more HTML here-->

   </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
findInvestmentPreApply: function() {
   if ($('investment') && $('the_form')) {
      var formItems = $$('.isa-option input');
      formItems.each(function(s,i){
         Event.observe(s, 'click', function() {highlightRadioChoice(s.id)});
      })
   }
},
```

I've tried various combinations of adding .bind(this) and .bindAsEventListener without any success.

The original code that worked looked something like this:

```
<label for="cautious" id="cautiousLabel" class="isa-option">
   <input type="radio" id="cautious" name="radios" value="cautious" onclick="highlightRadioChoice('cautious');" />Cautious Portfolio
</label>
```

and the highlightRadioChoice function called hasn't changed.

If it helps, the highlightRadioChoice function is in a different js file to the Event code which itself is in a js file of functions that run on page load to achieve a progressive enhancement approach.  I can't help thinking that if I move the highlightRadioChoice function into the file which runs on load it will work fine (ie. calling this.highlightRadioChoice(...)) but this would mean changing a whole load of other pages we don't want to at this stage.

Help me please StackOverflow!

========EDIT=========

With some help from Epoch, I've found that this rather elaborate function works in both IE and FF:

```
findInvestmentPreApply: function() {
   if ($('investment') && $('the_form')) {
      var formItems = $$('.isa-option');
      formItems.each(function(s){
         s.observe('click', function() {highlightRadioChoice(s.id.substring(0,s.id.indexOf('Label')))});
      })
   }
},
```

Still not sure why this should work and my previous code won't.

Answer (score 0):

This works in ie7 so do you have a specific error?

[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmvw5/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Your fiddle works on my IE7 but when I put the code into my page it doesn't.  I'm not getting any error message at all.

I put an alert inside the loop to make sure it was getting through that ok, and it is.

Comment: I'm glad it works, feel free to accept the answer and vote :)

Comment: I would accept your answer but on it's own it made no difference to my problem, it was only when I referenced the enclosing label id and then subscripted out the id of the enclosed input did it work.  I don't think the solution I've found is the right one and I'm still open to suggestions for a better one.

Comment: sure. you can also try moving to prototype 1.7 and using the Event.on method